# Website content doesn't show on my PC

Tags: wordpress, browser, dns, loading, browser-cache

I recently ordered a new domain and made the site using wordpress on different hosting. At first while propagation was taking place the domain only loaded the default content of the domain company (just plain URL), here is a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/2b67hu

After the DNS was pointed to my hosting it started working and I installed the theme and everything. All of a sudden after reloading the site a hundredth time it went back to the default content provided by the domain company (the screenshot above).

I would think that propagation is still taking placing and it might be jumping, but the site works perfectly on any other pc I checked (never loaded the site before on those pcs).

On my pc however, the site doesn't load on any browser. I cleared cache, used hard reload (ctrl + shift + R, f5, etc), disabled windows firewall, but still same thing.

Only when I changed my IP using HMA, it loaded the site normally. But once I disconnected from the fake IP, it goes back.

So basically site doesn't load new content, only the default from domain company, happened all of a sudden, only loads if I change my IP or if I use a different pc, probably would load on yours.

Please help I don't want to change my IP each time I want to load or work on the site :)

Thank you guys!!

Comment: The solution has to be posted as an *Answer* in the box bellow. [so] doesn't work like forums, please read the page [About]

Comment: I know, but as a new user I wasn't allowed to post an official answer so I posted it as a comment.

Comment: I think there's a time limit before you can post the answer. Probably you can now.

Comment: Awesome I did post the answer now, thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem. Will post the solution for others just in case:

1) Click your “Start” menu (Windows Orb on the taskbar of Windows 7 & Vista).

2) Select Control Panel.

3) Double-Click Network & Sharing Center or Network Connections Icon.

4) Click to Open “Local Area Connection”

5) Click “Properties”

6) Choose Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4), then click “Properties”

7) Click the radio button that says “Use the following DNS server addresses” and type in one of the below listed IP addresses in the “Preferred DNS Server” and “Alternate DNS Server” fields.

8) Click the OK button, the close all of the open windows.

9) Click on your “Start Menu” again.

10) Click “Run” on Windows Vista or earlier, or type the following into the search field in Windows 7.

11) Type cmd & hit the enter key.

12) Type ipconfig /flushdns

13) When it says that your DNS has been successfully flushed, close the window.

The website should load now. Hope this helps someone :)

---

DNS IPs you can use:

Genuity

- 4.2.2.1
- 4.2.2.2

Google

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4